# RegEx javascript match 2 consecutive occurence of character but not more

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help with regex. I have to match "{{" at the beginning of the string but not "{{{". I tried to use `^[{]{2}` but it matches for "{{{". I tried to match "{{{" with `^[^{]{3}` but I don't know how to match "{{" again.

I know I can probably get around it with a if statement. But I would like to do it in one shot within regex. Any Idea?

Comment: Am I crazy in saying it is as easy as this? http://regexr.com/3eef3

Comment: @anied i believe the OP wants to match a string beginning in `{{` but not `{{{`

Comment: @abc123 _Oh_.  I misunderstood-- yeah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @curtainsbaked Are you trying to match the two literal `{{` characters at the beginning of the string? Or match only strings which begin with `{{`?

Comment: Thanks @torazaburo - but abc123 already pointed that out and I already replied that I see my misunderstanding.

Comment: @anied Then you can delete your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/cQldyl/1)

`^{{[^{]` or `^[{]{2}[^{]` both will work

### Description

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
{{ matches the characters {{ literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character not present in the list below [^{]
    { matches the character { literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: But this will "eat' the third character.

Comment: @torazaburo this will only Not match a string with {{{ it isn't eating the.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that if you do `{{ab".replace(/^{{[^{]/, "foo")`, it will replace `{{a` with foo, not just the `{{`.

Comment: @torazaburo I completely agree, negative lookaheads would solve this.  But this was mentioned as a concern, OP just mentions matching it.  Either solution works, your solution solves for an extra case that mine doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookahead:

```js
const re = /^{{(?!{)/;

console.log("{{{".match(re));
console.log("{{a".match(re));
```